# Некорректное отображение гистограммы

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Если использовать стандартные настройки для графиков, то гистограмма отображает значения с минимальной частотой. если применить sns.set() то эти значения не видно. Кто поможет решить проблему?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: А что вы хотите получить то в итоге? У вас просто действительно много одних значений и минимум других, их в любом случае не будет видно на гистограмме. Но есть варианты: 1) разнести частые и редкие значения на две отдельные гистограммы; 2) рисовать гистограмму логарифма от счётчика, а не самого счётчика

Comment: Обе гистограммы сделаны абсолютно одинаково. Только на скрине с белым фоном и дефолтными настройками видны минимальные частоты. На другом скрине все тоже самое , только добавлено sns.set(),  и минимальные частоты уже не видны. Пробовал ylim(-100, ), svg отображение, figsize менял. Ничего не помогло. css темы надо крутить )